# Android studio says I need to upgrade to Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0 while I'm on 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter, android-app-bundle

I have a flutter app, which works perfectly. With `flutter build appbundle` I am able to build a signed app bundle without any errors. Now, I am trying to generate a signed app bundle and export the encrypted key to upload my app to the play store. However, when I go to Build -> Generate Signed App Bundle -> Android App Bundle I get the following error:

`Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher`

When I run `flutter build appbundle -v` I can see that I'm using Gradle 5.1.1 which according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) website suggests I am indeed using Gradle Android plugin 3.4.1

I've already tried setting my project structure to *Android-Gradle* instead of *Android*. However, now I'm not able to select the *Generate Signed App Bundle* anymore. I've also tried a lot of different Gradle and Android Gradle plugin version, but none of them seem to work. Android Studio etc are all updated (version 3.5.1). My Flutter and Dart plugins are also on the latest versions.

My main *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My *gradle-wrapper.properties*:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Part of *flutter build appbundle -v*:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
                    Gradle 5.1.1
 ------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_202-release (JetBrains s.r.o 25.202-b03)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

I am not sure what to do anymore, so any suggestions will help!

Comment: Could you include the output from the command-line for which gradle and gradle -v in the question? This will help give a more complete picture. Also can you show output from when you build the android project from within AS?

Comment: Gradle output is `'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`, so I guess something is wrong there. Also, under the build option I am only able to generate APKs or App Bundle, I'm not able to build the Android project anywhere. Guess something is wrong with my settings in general

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the same exact issue; trying to enable Code Signing via exporting an encrypted key from Android Studio.